# Can't edit textbox content inside TinyMCE Version > 3.4.5 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tinymce

In the TinyMCE Version 3.4.6 and higher I can't edit text of  which are inside TinyMCE. But in TinyMCE 3.4.5 and lower that's works perfect. What's changed? How can I edit them in the lates versions of TinyMCE?

In Firefox and Opera everything is OK!

**Examples:**

3.4.5: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/f4caab

3.4.6: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/e4caab

Comment: i can edit both textareas using FF16

Comment: @Thariama yep, I know about FF. But this topic about Chrome :)

Comment: +1 sry, was my fault. yes, i can confirm this behaviour

Comment: you should file a bug report: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_bugs.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug appeared in this commit: https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/e26e02920b07e3195cf4873bf95796e87d769177

I've left the comment on the bug tracker. Waiting for solution: http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5657